# Create schema and populate data with Docker and Sql Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker compose to create a container with a mssql db like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services: 
  db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - ./db-schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db-schema.sql
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "CiaoCiao69!"
```

The script isn't executed and schema is not created after I launch
`docker compose build` and `docker compose up`.

What am I doing wrong? My purpose is to "pack" everything needed to run locally a web project with ASP.NET

Comment: Why do you expect that script to get executed? Unless the Dockerfile has a RUN or CMD command to execute that file, that's just a mounted file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I saw in some StackOverflow anwsers that that's the way to, because that `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder is supposed to host sql scripts to be run at startup. May this be only Postgres related?